# Visual studio designer not displaying content correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I compile and run the code to my application, the buttons and text from that window doesn't appear in the same location on the running application as in the designer tab.  All other windows appear correctly when run.  Any ideals? Here are a few pictures of the problem.

Picture of the designer: 
[image]

Picture of the program when running: 
[image]

Comment: Without any code to look at, picture's don't do much help as we can not see the underlying code that actually make's the design. Could you please  update your post and include the **.designer** file for your form you are having issue's with. Also can you confirm that you **are not changing form objects at runtime**.

Comment: It looks like the runtime splash screen is wider then the one in the designer.

Answer (score -1):

To have the text and button to stay in the middle of the screen add Anchor Left Right Top

[image: Anchor]

Comment: Without a proper question this was the best answer I could come up with as to what is going on.  I see your running screen is bigger then the one in the VS designer.  I see that the button was centered properly so the anchor tags are set on the button but not on the 3 labels above the button. If you down vote then leave a comment as to why the answer is wrong.